# how to send parameters using curl X post in Dockercontainer

Tags: docker, falconframework

I am running a Dockercontainer. My Falcon app.py looks like:

```py
import falcon

class Workers:
    def on_post(self, expedice, celkem_pracovniku, req, resp):
        
        output = str(
            {
                "expedice": expedice,
                "celkem_pracovniku": celkem_pracovniku

            }
        )


        resp.text = output

        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_OK


app = application = falcon.API()
app.add_route("/pozice_skladApi/v1/pracovnici", Workers())
```

I am running a docker image on port 8082:80, but I dont now how can I run the `/pozice_skladApi/v1/pracovnici` exactly. I try:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8082/pozice_skladApi/v1/pracovnici -d "knihy-praha" 10` but I got `{"title": "500 Internal Server Error"}`. What I do wrong, please?

Comment: If you're getting an HTTP 500 error, you're correctly reaching the container.  To simplify the setup, do you get the same error running the same code without Docker in a virtual environment?  Is there an interesting error in the container logs?

Comment: @DavidMaze when I run the same code in my venv I get no errors. I think there muset something wrong with the `curl -X POST http://localhost:8082/pozice_skladApi/v1/pracovnici -d "knihy-praha" 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `on_post` function. Correct form is:

```py
    def on_post(self, req, resp):

        try:
            data = req.media
        except:
            raise falcon.HTTPBadRequest(description="Missing post data.")

        expedice = data.get("expedice")
        celkem_pracovniku = data.get("celkem_pracovniku")
```

Then you can use following command in the terminal: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"expedice": "knihy-praha", "celkem_pracovniku": 10}' http://localhost:8082/pozice_skladApi/v1/pracovnici`